# How to pass multiple variables to a function in Python (used in packages such as PSO and GA)

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

some packages in Python use functions (def) as a objective function or fitness function for optimization problems, such as https://pypi.org/project/pyswarms/ and https://pypi.org/project/geneticalgorithm/

For example

```
def f(X):
    return np.sum(X)
```

This is the default setup for the package and I cannot define:

```
def f(X, Y):
    return np.sum(X) + np.sum(Y)
```

These functions have only X as input and I wonder how could I use more than one variable as input (x and y for example), or even variables with multiple indexes.

I was able to solve some problems converting multiple variables in a single array; however, that is a hard work in my point of view.

Can someone, please, provide any tip in this subject?

Thank you

Comment: I think it might help clarify the problem if you give an example of the approach you're currently using.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to take a look into map().

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

The map() function applies a given function to each item of an iterable (list, tuple etc.) and returns an iterator.

```
def func(a):
    return a*a

cluster = [5,10,15,20]

list(map(func, cluster))

[25, 100, 225, 400]
```

or also, with lambda functions:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

squared = map(lambda num: num ** 2, numbers)

list(squared)

[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I think that would help with transformations in my code, and not to use more than one variable in the function of the problem. Although, your suggestion gave me an insight on creating a "map" function to convert X to the variables that I wish.

Answer (score 0):

According to the geneticalalgorithm's documentation:

> Notice that we define the function f so that its output is the objective function we want to minimize where the input is the set of X (decision variables).

Example from the documentation (chapter 'Optimization problems with constraints'):

```
def f(X):
    pen = 0
    if X[0] + X[1] < 2:
        pen = 500 + 1000 * (2 - X[0] - X[1])
    return np.sum(X) + pen

varbound = np.array([[0, 10]] * 3)    
model = ga(function=f, dimension=3, variable_type='real', variable_boundaries=varbound)    
model.run()
```

Solution for your example:

```
def f(X):
    return np.sum(X[0]) + np.sum(X[1])
```

Comment: In this case, X[0] and X[1] could not be an array I believe, since the parameter dimension=3 does not accept a list or tuple. Thus, X[0] and X[1] would be just a single variable